# select the right numbers based on a condition

Tags: performance-tuning, fitting, finance, modeling

I want to optimize my stock portfolio based on three components:

1. the price of the different stocks
2. the number to buy of each of the stocks
3. the expected return of each stock (after 12 months)

For example, I can choose from 4 different stocks

- stock A: price: 5, Number to buy: Anumb, expected return: 0.3
- stock B: price: 7, Number to buy: Bnumb, expected return: 0.5
- stock C: price: 9, Number to buy: Cnumb, expected return: 0.7
- stock D: price: 11, Number to buy: Dnumb, expected return: 0.9

My budget is fixed: 1000
The number to buy of each stock is or zero, a integer and always positive

the model looks like:

```
5.Anumb + 7.Bnumb + 9.Cnumb + 11.Dnumb <= 1000

5.Anumb.0,3 + 7.Bnumb.0,5 + 9*Cnumb*.7 + 11.Dnumb.0,9 = Maximum
```

What is the most efficient way to do in Mathematica?

My solution is like

```
data =Table[{a, b, c, d, 5 a + 7 b + 9 c + 11 d == 1000}, {a, 0, 
  Round[N[1000/5]]}, {b, 0, Round[N[1000/7]]}, {c, 0, 
  Round[N[1000/9]]}, {d, 0, Round[N[1000/11]]}];
```

Then take only the options which are 'True'. Calculate each true-options with the expected return. Then select the maximum value.
The problem is: it takes to much time.

Comment: This looks like a fairly classical [linear optimization problem](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/ConstrainedOptimizationLinearProgramming.html) for which there are various Mathematica function. For example: ``Maximize[{5 Anumb*0.3 + 7*Bnumb*0.5 + 9*Cnumb*0.7 + 11*Dnumb*0.9, 5 Anumb + 7 Bnumb + 9 Cnumb + 11 Dnumb <= 1000}, {Anumb, Bnumb, Cnumb, Dnumb}, PositiveReals]``.

Comment: looks interesting. But the sum of bought stocks is with this formula 5501 and the budget is 1000. Do you have a suggestion?

Comment: I don't think so. The optimal solution is ``{Anumb -> 0., Bnumb -> 0., Cnumb -> 0., Dnumb -> 90.9091}`` which gives the expected return $900$ and the price $90.9091\times11=1000$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might like to generalize this problem to work with any number of stocks using a list of `prices` and `returns`. This eliminates a lot of extra typing and allows you make quick changes to the lists of prices and returns. Let's use your examples and a modified copy of Domen's comment.

```
prices = {5, 7, 9, 11};
returns = {.3, .5, .7, .9};
stocks = stock[#] &/@ Range[Length[prices]];
sol = Maximize[Total[stocks prices returns],
  Total[stocks prices] <= 1000, stocks, PositiveIntegers]
(* {892.4, {stock[1] -> 1, stock[2] -> 1, stock[3] -> 1, stock[4] -> 89}} *)
```

Then the number of each stock to buy is `stocks /. Last@sol`, the total investment is `Total[stocks prices] /. Last@sol`.

```
stocks /. Last@sol
(* {1, 1, 1, 89} *)
Total[stocks prices] /. Last@sol
(* 1000 *)
```

Alternatively, we can solve with real values, and adjust for integer number of stocks, to get total investment and total return.

```
sol = Maximize[Total[stocks prices returns],
  Total[stocks prices] <= 1000, stocks, PositiveReals];
Floor[stocks] /. Last@sol
(* {0, 0, 0, 90} *)
Total[Floor[stocks] prices] /. Last@sol
(* 990 *)
Total[Floor[stocks] prices returns] /. Last@sol
(* 891. *)
```